# Why The problem in void error with "return" -fpermissive

Tags: c++, vector

Cannot understand what is the problem. There is an error: return-statement with a value, in function returning ‘void’ [-fpermissive]
**return result;**

````
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void print(const vector<int>& v)
{
    int N = 2;
    vector<int> result(v.size());
    size_t pos = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0;i < v.size(); i++)
{
    pos = i*N;
        if (pos >= v.size()) pos %= (v.size());
    result[i] = v[pos];
}
return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    print(v);

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `void print(const vector<int>& v)` does not expect to return a value.

Comment: Well, what do you expect to happen?  You told the compiler the return type is `void`, meaning it doesn't return anything, and now you're telling it inside the function to instead return a `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have declared that the function returns `void`. This means that the function doesn't return a value. However, you also have a return statement that returns a value. Returning a value from a function that doesn't return a value is a contradiction. This is a violation of rules of the language and the program is ill-formed.

Ways to fix this bug are:

1. Either change the declaration of the function so that the return type matches the type of the value given to the return statement.
2. Or remove the return statement.